# Can a person with thrombocytopenia marry a thalassemia carrier?

Tags: blood, risks, thrombocytopenia, carrier-genetic

Can a person with thrombocytopenia marry a thalassemia carrier? Will there be any effect to the child? For example a thalassemia carrier and his partner who is under medication of thrombocytopenia, both are having normal life without any complication. If they got married, will the children be at any risk?

Comment: Please, @askingtoomuch, you really need to tell us what you know about both conditions and the genetics. You also need to tell us the present extent of the conditions in both parties before someone can answer you. Why you expect someone to guess at this important information and then research it for you is a kind of a mystery to me.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I searched but couldn't get much information about it compared to a couple with thalassemia. Thinking of going to seek a doctor advice soon so just trying my luck here. Adding more info to my question, a thalassemia carrier and his partner who is under medication of thrombocytopenia, both are having normal life without any complication. If they got married, will the children be at any risk?

Comment: Please edit that - and any other information you have (what is the cause of the thrombocytopenia?) - into your question, or at best, it will be a guess, and guesses don't really help anyone. Thanks!